# Confirm box when link is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("a.route").live('click', function() { // live is better
        $("#results").load( $(this).attr('href') );
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

That's the code, how can I incorporate the code you just gave me?

Comment: You should accept answers by clicking the hollow check.

Answer (score 2):

The `Confirm` dialog returns true if the user clicks the OK button, or false if the user clicks on the Cancel button. You can use this value to trigger your script if they've clicked OK like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("a.route").live('click', function() {
        if (confirm("Are you sure?")) {
            $("#results").load( $(this).attr('href') );
        }
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use a custom box you could do it like that:

test link: http://jsfiddle.net/myDry/

```
function blockmeornot(extlink) {
    var oherf = $(extlink).attr('href')
    var msgboxID = 'areyousure'
    var msgbox = '<div id="' + msgboxID +'"><div><p> put your message here </p><a class="yes" href="' + oherf + '"> yes </a> <a class="no" href="#"> no </a></div></div>'
    $('body').append(msgbox)
    $('#' + msgboxID + ' a.no').live('click', function(){ $('#' + msgboxID).fadeOut(400, function(){$(this).remove()}) })
}

$('a.external').click(function(){ blockmeornot(this); return false })
```

Comment: I am happy with the jquery confirm function, I just want it to trigger the code above if user clicks OK.

Comment: its just for the eye candy. do whatever you want with it :P so could you please an accept a answer?